# In SQL i'm trying to return the first set of numerical values after a specific word sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use a translator because my English is not good.
I need your help with something.
I'm working in a hospital.
I want to search the field where patient complaints are kept in both the sql server and the table.
There are numerical and verbal expressions in patient complaints. I want to get the numeric expression after the specified word or expression.

Sample:

The patient has a headache. Weight: 156 kg, Height: 170 cm

Example with a function:

The patient has a headache. Weight: 65.5 kg, height: 170 cm, discharged'
complaint

```
select patientstringfunction(patient,'Weight:')
from patient
--65.5

select patientstringfunction(patient,'height:')
from patient
--170
```

Comment: T-SQL (the dialect used by SQL Server) is very poor at string processing. A function like this is difficult to write and that's a *simple* case; as text gets more complicated it becomes harder and harder. I strongly suggest moving string processing to the client side, especially if you want reliable results.

Comment: People will always take shortcuts, write inconsistently, use abbreviations, make spelling mistakes, etc. If people are entering this information as text, then your goal is likely to be impossible if you want a high level of accuracy / correctness.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I prepared a sql. It solved my problem. I share it for others to benefit. Thanks.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[StringIcindeIfadeBul]
    (@Cumle VARCHAR (MAX)
   , @Aranan VARCHAR (100))
RETURNS VARCHAR (MAX)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Cikti VARCHAR (2000) ;
        DECLARE @KarakterSayisi INT =
                    (
                        SELECT  CHARINDEX( @Aranan, @Cumle )
                    ) ;

        DECLARE @IlkKarakterSayisi INT =
                    (
                        SELECT  CHARINDEX( ' ', @Cumle, @KarakterSayisi )
                    ) ;
        IF @IlkKarakterSayisi = 0
            SET @IlkKarakterSayisi = LEN( @Cumle ) + 1 ;
        BEGIN
            SET @Cikti
                = REPLACE(
                             SUBSTRING(
                                          @Cumle
                                        , @KarakterSayisi
                                        , @IlkKarakterSayisi - @KarakterSayisi
                                      )
                           , @Aranan
                           , ''
                         ) ;
        END ;
        RETURN @Cikti ;

    END ;
```